# How to detect the difference between an interface and an abstract class?

Tags: c#, system.type

Given the following types:

```
public interface Interface { }
public abstract class Abstract { }
```

Why is this:

```
typeof(Interface).IsAbstract == true;
```

Note the `IsInterface` exists to check if it is an interface:

```
typeof(Abstract).IsInterface == false;
```

Comment: By definition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isabstract?view=netcore-3.1.

"returns true in the following cases: 1. The current type is abstract; that is, it cannot be instantiated, but can only serve as the base class for derived classes. (...) 2. The current type is an interface." What is the point of the question, the property behaves as-documented. Are you asking for the reason it was designed that way?

Comment: So in order to check if it is an abstract i should check both properties. IsAbstract actually means IsAbstractOrInterface?

Comment: @V0ldek Might be an open door for you but it might help me understand the design of the languages. Taking everything for granted keeps you in the dark.

Comment: My point is that if you're asking about the rationale behind the semantics you should ask about that directly. Right now the question gives a vibe of "I'm too lazy to google the docs, tell me how this property works", which is unlikely to help other people on SO in the future.

Comment: @V0ldek I rephrased my question hopefully this helps other people.

Comment: The `abstract` is a modifier specifying that whatever it modifies is abstract. `interface` is abstract by default so no need to specifically add the modifier. (and it doesn't only go for classes and interfaces, you can also define abstract methods and other things and when getting the `MethodInfo` through reflection there is once again the `IsAbstract` boolean). So of all the things that can be abstract an `abstract class` is just a subset (same as `interface`)

Comment: The reason behind this API decision is likely because the intermediate language (IL) that C# compiles into requires that if a type is marked `interface`, it must also be marked `abstract`. ECMA-335 II.22.37 rule 23: *An Interface shall have Flags.Abstract = 1*. The reflection API probably thinks in terms of IL instead of C# since the API can be used from VB.NET, F#, etc. as well. As to why the spec has that requirement, I can't definitively answer.

Comment: Not sure of why some people would close such question as `opinion-based` since it is a clear one and can have clear answers. It could be closed with `Needs details or clarity` or an other reason if it is not well explained but not as opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isabstract?view=netcore-3.1#remarks):

> The IsAbstract property returns true in the following cases:
>
> - The current type is abstract; that is, it cannot be instantiated, but    can only serve as the base class for derived classes. In C#,
>   abstract    classes are marked with the abstract keyword; in Visual
>   Basic, they    are marked with the MustInherit keyword.
> - **The current type is an interface.**

So an interface is considered abstract because it cannot be instantiated.

If you want to determine that a type is an *abstract class*, you should do the following:

```
typeof(YourType).IsClass && typeof(YourType).IsAbstract
```

Comment: So is it correct to say if it is abstract is it IsAbstract but not an interface and it is an interface if IsInterface (and IsAbstract) holds

Comment: @Wouter No. `IsAbstract` would be true for an abstract class or an interface, but `IsInterface` is only true for interfaces.

Comment: I guess i misunderstood the term _abstract_ for abstract class as opposed to interface being an interface. Both are _abstract_ types.

Comment: @Wouter In this context `IsAbstract` is an indicator that a given type is "_abstract and must be overridden_" i.e. cannot be instantiated directly. It does not literally mean the type is an abstract class.